# Provided the heat of vaporization of a liquid, how would one determine the surface area of a plate needed to dissipate a given amount watts?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity, dissipation

I am starting on the basic engineering of a DIY two-phase liquid immersion cooling for a personal computer. I have located a few potential liquids for use, notably [3M's Novec 7000 series of products](https://multimedia.3m.com/mws/media/1801351O/data-center-immersion-cooling-aplications-with-3m-novec-engineered-fluids-line-card.pdf). I am trying to determine a good *over*-**estimate** of the surface area of a cooling plate needed to properly dissipate the heat generated by the main component(s). My main issue is that I cannot figure out how to go from the specific energy of the liquid ($142 J/g$) to the amount of power, for example, ($100W$) I wish to dissipate.

I can locate and define a few variables, but I am not sure how to fit them all together.

- Generating $100 J/s$ ($100W$)
- Dissipating onto $Xm^2$ surface area of a copper plate
- Copper has a thermal conductivity of $384.1 W/mK$
- Plate is in direct contact with liquid with a heat of vaporization of $142J/g$

Overall, I just don't see **how to reconcile the heat flow measured in $J/s$ against the specific energy of the liquid measured in $J/g$**. I keep getting stuck at attempting to cancel out $s$ in the thermal conductivity of copper ($W/mK=J/msK$) by dividing by $m^2$ of surface area..

Comment: You might want to research heat pipes.  I expect that a range of heat transfer rates are available for sale.

Comment: I'm familiar with them, though I'm much more interested in a proper two-phase liquid immersion build. I've ran through every other type of cooling (fans, more fans, AIO, custom loops, TECs, bong tree, CO2, N2, etc). Only two left on my list is an AC cold head and immersion. Working on the cheaper option first.